# Лицензирование программного обеспечения под Android

Tags: android

Добрый день.
Хотелось бы узать о лицензировании разработки ПО.
Под какой лицензией распространяется? Публикация? Сертификация?

Answer (score 3):

В принципе вы можете распространять свои приложения под какой угодно лицензией, но в случае если распространение будет вестись через Android Market (тьфу теперь Android Play), то вы должны согласиться на некое ограничение своих прав, а именно согласиться на [данное соглашение](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html).

В принципе кроме Маркета есть еще несколько способов распространения приложения (правда, Маркет надо признать самый лучший), так что это вопрос выбора.

Касаемо лицензирования - в Android'е есть такое понятие как [LVL](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html) (License Verification Library) - довольно удобная вещь - некая защита от копирования. Фактически проверяет привязку приложения к Google аккаунту

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score -1):

[Android Open Source Project license](http://source.android.com/source/licenses.html).

Даже не знаю, как правильно комментировать такие вопросы. =)

Comment: А зря! В приведенной ссылке речь идет о лицензии на Android, а человек спрашивает о лицензировании приложений под Android!